# How build app in production mode, Ionic3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want build my app on ionic 3 to production mode. I try

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

but I have always error:

> Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a
>   circular dependencies (might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts
>   files.

my package.json look like as:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-wordpress",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "IonicThemes",
  "homepage": "https://ionicthemes.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "android-versions": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "ionic": "3.12.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

also my npm-debug.log has next errors

```
160758 error Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
160759 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"
160760 error node v4.8.4
160761 error npm  v2.15.11
160762 error code EPEERINVALID
160763 error peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core@3.12.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
160763 error peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/native-storage@4.5.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
160763 error peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
160763 error peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/status-bar@3.12.1 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
160764 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

please help me find a mistake. if run app in default mode, it is work fine

> ionic cordova run android

I googled a lot before asking. Thanks.

Comment: check with all providers in app.module.ts

Comment: @Edison, please, look at the my screen http://joxi.ru/J2b4x4VT4eMGMr . I have one provider and service but they both include to providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `storage` from `providers` in your `app.module.ts`, explanation can be found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/prod-build-throws-undefined-provider-error/85814/4).

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [ storage, ... ]
});
```

> Note: Since @ionic/storage 2.x.x, we need to import
>   `IonicStorageModule` instead of `storage`.